# How to support right-to-left in xamarin.forms

Tags: internationalization, xamarin.forms, right-to-left

How do I support right-to-left direction of pages in xamarin.forms? I have tried different layouts such as `RelativeLayout` and `StackLayout` and set its `HorizontalOptions` to `start` or `end`, but it does not swap the element. Anybody have any idea how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xamarin have started (or at least announced) work on internationalisation, including RTL. Currently it is not in yet though. A workaround for this in e.g. `ListView` is to create multiple list item templates with LTR/RTL directions and use them according to the current UI culture. For other controls your best bet would be to implement a renderer for each control type and change its `HorizontalOptions` or `XAlignment` according to the UI culture. You're basically forced to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

i have create custom markup extension will help you to make rtl and ltr layout support the extension have these types :

- GridLength
- LayoutOption
- TextAlignment
- Int
- String
- ResourceKey
- Thickness

**EX**: if you want to make you label HorizontalOptions rtl when language is arabic and ltr when its english you do it :
 HorizontalOptions="{UIExtensions:UIDirection Type=LayoutOption, LTR=Start, RTL=End}"

https://gist.github.com/ads90/ff5c69410d2654dcad3ed8d275d7ca20